# libcurl-dev package for yocto

Tags: libcurl, yocto

My project has a dependency on native curl (library, header, etc.)
On Ubuntu, I apt-installed libcurl4-gnutls-dev, which brought everything I needed to my /usr/lib and /usr/include directories. Moreover, I don't know how, but some how, in my cmake build, I also have `find_package(CURL)` working just fine.

I now need to port my project to Yocto (Cisco IR1101 router). Installing with **opkg** libcurl4 works just fine, but it only brings the *.so files. curl.h is (rightfully) missing.

I cannot find any development package, or the form libcurl-dev, libcurl4-dev, libcurl4-gnutls-dev, etc.

Alternatively, I tried to build the sources (github/curl/curl - appears to be a cmake project), but asking me openssl and other dependencies not available on my machine.